# Eloquent search through many columns and relevant sorting

Tags: mysql, laravel, orm, eloquent

I have a search query looking for books in the database. It searches for titles and authors.

```
$searchQuery = explode(" ", $searchString);
$results = $this
                ->where(function ($query) use($searchQuery) {
                    for ($i = 0; $i < count($searchQuery); $i++){
                        $query->orwhere('title', 'LIKE',  '%' . $searchQuery[$i] .'%');
                    }
                })
                ->orWhereHas('authors', function ($query) use ($searchQuery)  {
                    for ($i = 0; $i < count($searchQuery); $i++){
                        $query->orwhere('author', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchQuery[$i] .'%');
                    }
                })
                ->get();
```

How can i optimize it so shows the entry with title "**The Magic Mountain**" and author "**Thomas Mann**" first?

Edit: This is the mysql version:

```html
select * from `books_catalogue` where (`title` LIKE '%magic%' or `title` LIKE '%mountain%' or `title` LIKE '%thomas%' or `title` LIKE '%mann%') or exists (select * from `authors` inner join `author_books_catalogue` on `authors`.`id` = `author_books_catalogue`.`author_id` where `author_books_catalogue`.`books_catalogue_id` = `books_catalogue`.`id` and (`author` LIKE '%magic%' or `author` LIKE '%mountain%' or `author` LIKE '%thomas%' or `author` LIKE '%mann')) or (`query` LIKE '%magic%' or `query` LIKE '%mountain%' or `query` LIKE '%thomas%' or `query` LIKE '%mann%');
```

Comment: Why are you using a loop and not just using a query where you can search for the specific author with the title ? Why are you using `LIKE` ?

Comment: loop: because i cut the search string into an array, like: because a search isn't identical, eg in the database it might be "thomas mann" and the search query "mann"

Comment: But what do you wanna to optimize if you can not change the LIKE clause. With LIKE you always get more result which can be the result. Could you be more specific what you exactly want

Comment: I want to optimize the order. The first item should be the one with the most matches, not just the first one found.

Comment: @DaveDriesmans I think you can then implement `count(*) as count` `groupBy(book_id)` and `orderBy('count')`. If needed, I'll post the implementation example in answer. let me know

Comment: @jaysingkar i don't see how this can help.

Comment: @DaveDriesmans sorry I assumed the query while posting the comment. BTW, what do you mean by most matches. like if given search term is present in both Title and Author name, it should diplay first ?

Comment: @jaysingkar exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a FULLTEXT field that contains title and authors in a varchar. That way i could use Mysql match feature. That works fluently and fast.

The code now looks like this:

```html
 $results = $this
                ->whereRaw("MATCH (search_summary) AGAINST ('".$searchString."')  ORDER BY MATCH(search_summary) AGAINST('".$searchString."') ASC, books_catalogue.priority DESC;")
                ->get();
```